# aznbsetup.sh startup file for Azure Notebooks is not run

Tags: azure, azure-notebooks

I've create the Azure Notebooks library with ['aznbsetup.sh'](https://notebooks.azure.com/help/jupyter-notebooks/server-initialization) startup file.

File doesn't run then I open the library, and `.aznbsetup.log` is not created.

File content is simple

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull
```

So I don't know what's happening and how to debug it

Answer (score 1):

After conversation [at AzureNotebooks official GH repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks/issues/424), the answer is

1. [Doc](https://notebooks.azure.com/help/jupyter-notebooks/server-initialization) is outdated
2. Log stored in `.nb.setup.log` (setup log for library), not in `aznbsetup.log` (doesn't exist anymore)